# How to shrink Linux partition (sda2, type is Linux LVM)

Tags: linux, lvm, partition, shrink

I have sda disk with 2 partitions. The second partition sda2(which is LVM) is 1.4TB in size and want to shrink to 50GB. I reduced Logical volume to 50GB but when I run vgdisplay it shows Free PE / Size 1.33 TiB. I want this free space to have sda and not sda2 for to create sda3 partition which I want not to be formatted (Who is familiar with Oracle and asm , I will clarify that I want sda3 to mark as an asm disk)

So I want to take 1.33 TiB from  sda2 and give it to sda, how?  Please, help.

[image: fdisk -l]

[image: pvdisplay]

[image: vgdisplay]

[image: lvdisplay]

Comment: Is it not possible for oracle to use a logical volume?  It seems that would be easier to do rather than repartitioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must resize the LVM physical volume after you have reduced the partition on the filesystem with fdisk.

I have not the possibility to confirm the exact steps right now, so you should get someone to review the steps before you perform them.

#### 1. Backup your data!

In case something goes wrong, make sure you have your data backed up.

#### 2. Resize the filesystem

`resize2fs -p /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 50GB`

#### 3. Resize the logical volume

`lvresize -L50G /dev/VolGroup/LogVol00`

#### 4. Backup partition table

`sfdisk -d /dev/sda > /var/tmp/partition-table.txt`

#### 5. Delete /dev/sda2 partition

Use `fdisk` to delete the partition `/dev/sda2`

#### 6. Create a new /dev/sda2 partition

Create a new partion with the exact same starting offset as your former partition (this should be default) and make it only 50G

#### 7. Resize the LVM Physical Volume

`pvresize /dev/sda2`

Comment: thank you for response. Can you provide me with the steps how to shrink the /dev/sda2 partition to 50GB using fdisk? (without loosing any data)

Comment: Edited post with steps for shrinking. Maybe the following URL can help you too http://fedorasolved.org/Members/zcat/shrink-lvm-for-new-partition

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have backups!!

That being said, for physical partitions, I have had a lot of luck with gparted whether windows or linux.

Boot off gparted cd and it gives you a nice gui to resize your partitions.